# In Ember.js, what is the proper way to get the current controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Currently, I have a mixin adding `currentController` property you can use to get the controller for the current route. I need it to be bindable so this is my code:

```
// client controller should be adding 'application' to its needs array
export default Ember.Mixin.create({

  _appController: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application'),

  currentController: function () {
    var currentRouteName = this.get('_appController').get('currentRouteName');
    return this.controllerFor(currentRouteName);
  }.property('_appController.currentRouteName')

});
```

But the use of `controllerFor` is deprecated in favor of needs. So, how should I do? Thank you.

Comment: why do you need to access the current route's controller? what are you trying to do?

Comment: There are 'controller' property in Ember.Route 
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_controller

Is this is what you need?

And what about nested routes - there are several active controllers at page

Comment: @VasilVanchuk, yes, with nested routes there are more than one controller active but only one is the leaf which correspond with the controller for the `currentRouteName`.

@Jaime, I have a generic tabbed view. Tabs should be enabled or not depending on a property inside the model of the controller for the current route.

Comment: @VasilVanchuk about the property yoou're referring, it should be perfect but how can I access to the current route object (not the name)?

Comment: you dont need all that current route name stuff to access the current controller... `this.controller` in a route will be the current route's controller.

Comment: Where from do you need access? ( And what for? ) - It's bad design create such mixins

Comment: I need access from a controller. I have a resource with sub resources. Sub resources are shown nested in the view of the resource. I need the active view of the resource to be configured attending to some subresource properties.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `this.controllerFor()` in your code, I'm assuming you are in the route context. Route has a `controller` property, you do not need a mixin. Example:

```
// Use this.controller in your route to get the current controller
var currentController = this.controller;
```

Comment: I'm in  the controller context. A controller for a generic tab view needs to be configured using data from the model of a nested route exposed to its controller. I need access to that controller.